# Error on mac after upgrading dependencies androidx/room/RoomProcessor has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, jvm

Here is the total error

```
androidx/room/RoomProcessor has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Here is my project level gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.10'
    ext.hilt_version = '2.45'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
  //      maven ()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    //    maven()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is my module level gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
//    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'


}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(8))
    }
}



//apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdk 33
    buildToolsVersion '33.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.plcoding.multipleroomtables"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    kapt { correctErrorTypes true }

}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.5"
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'

    // Room
    //implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5"
    //kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.0"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0"
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0'


    // Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.0"

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'

    // Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.0"

    // Hilt dependencies
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
 //   implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"

    // For instrumentation tests
    androidTestImplementation  'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.45'
    kaptAndroidTest 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.45'

    // For local unit tests
    testImplementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.45'
    kaptTest 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.45'
}
```

And my IDE is using version 11 in the android studio application contents folder.

I have tried changing/removing the compile options to compatibility 11 to 1_18 and still getting the same error.

I have also tried removing the jvmToolchain block as well.

What are the correct version and configurations I should be looking for?  Is the issue that I need to change the version of Android Room I am using?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

For me what solved it was specifying:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '11'
}
```

in the module's build.gradle file instead of targeting JAVA 8.